# Mailcow (postfix) - allow sending unencrypted mails (SMTP port 25)

Tags: linux, email, postfix, smtp, email-server

How can I allow to send unencrypted mails using SMTP port 25 with (plain text) password authentification - without SSL/TLS? I need to enable this, because I have some old IP cameras that are not able to use an encryption to send emails...

I already commented out "smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes" in the postfix main.cf file at /opt/mailcow/data/conf/postfix/main.cf, but now I get the error message "Relay access denied" when I try to send an email to an external domain's address. At least I can send emails to myself (on my mailserver) now using port 25 without encryption, but I need to send emails to external addresses.

Comment: Why are the cameras connecting to port 25 instead of port 587?

Comment: This is the default setting and the firmware is quite old. That's the reason why I can't use SSL/TLS with these devices to send emails. I can set the port to 587, but if I try to send an email using port 587 without encryption (e.g. with thunderbird), I get the error "5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first."

Comment: Set up a mail relay on the LAN the IP cameras are on, configure it to allow by network and xfer mail to your real mail server

Comment: Okay, that would work, but the problem is, that the IP cameras aren't in my LAN. These are cameras at different locations that should send mails to my public mailserver over the internet and I thought mailcow would be perfect for this. So, I guess it isn't possible to just allow unencrypted SMTP (with username and password authentication), right?

Comment: Okay, now I've finally got it working without setting up a relay inside the LAN and/or adding IP addresses to `mynetworks` in the Postfix configuration.

I've set the value of the parameter `smtpd_tls_auth_only` in Postfix's main.cf from "yes" to "no". I also allowed SASL authentication for SMTP on port 25 in Postfix's master.cf file by changing the value for `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable` from "no" to "yes".

Now I can send e-mails (with a correct user authentication) via SMTP using port 25 without encryption as well as using e.g. port 465 with SSL/TLS. But thanks for the quick answers!

Comment: If you solved this yourself, you should post an answer detailing what you did. Comments are only temporary and some people cannot see them at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working without setting up a relay inside the LAN and/or adding IP addresses to `mynetworks` in the Postfix configuration. I've set the value of the parameter `smtpd_tls_auth_only` in Postfix's main.cf from "yes" to "no". I also allowed SASL authentication for SMTP on port 25 in Postfix's master.cf file by changing the value for `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable` from "no" to "yes".

Now I can send e-mails (with a correct user authentication) via SMTP using port 25 without encryption as well as using e.g. port 465 with SSL/TLS.

Comment: Thank you Weston. This answer would be more helpful if it was explicit in the steps taken

Answer (score 0):

> At least I can send emails to myself (on my mailserver) now using port 25 without encryption, but I need to send emails to external addresses.

You can send messages to email address "on your mailserver" and make procmail script forward the messages **after inspection** to external email address e.g. the script may verify sending IP address.